# Azure DevOps deployment pipeline failing with [error]Error: Cannot find any file based on /Users/runner/work/1/s/XYZ/**/ABC.ipa

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-artifacts

Artifact is downloaded to '/Users/runner/work/1/' and the deployment task is looking for the artifact at '/Users/runner/work/1/s/XYZ/**/ABC.ipa'.

In build stage, artifacts are published to 'PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/${{parameters.env}}'' and in deployment, artifacts are accessed using ''$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/XYZ/**/ABC.ipa''

Please help to access the ipa file correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Two pre-defined variables are used but they points to different folder structures(doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)):
`build.artifactstagingdirectory`: The local path on the agent where any artifacts are copied to before being pushed to their destination. For example: `c:\agent_work\1\a`, not have `s` folder.

`System.DefaultWorkingDirectory`: The local path on the agent where your source code files are downloaded. For example: `c:\agent_work\1\s`.

It's recommended to add a powershell task adhere to list all files in the directory and subdirectory, so that we can find where the files are stored on the agent. code sample:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  name: listfiles
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'Get-ChildItem -Path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) -Recurse -File'
```

After we confirm where the file resides, we can modify the path for the task so the file can be found.

Comment: Hi @Sneha Dominic, is it helpful? Let me know if there's further queries, thanks.